# Inverse Laplace of the Complex conjugate of the Laplace transform

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, laplace-transform

Let the Laplace transform of *f(t)* be *F(s)* and let the inverse Laplace transform of *F(s**) be *g(t)*. is there a theorem relating *f(t)* and *g(t)*? Basically, looking for a way to calculate *g(t)* from *f(t)* without the need of calculating the inverse Laplace integral of *F(s**)

Comment: complex conjugate? What is $S^*$?

Comment: the title says something else than what is written in the post, if $g(t)$ is the inverse Laplace transform of $F^\ast(s)$ then $f(t)=g^\ast(t)$.

Comment: s is a complex variable and s* it's complex conjugate: s=a+ib,  s*=a-ib. (I fixed the cap S, should have been lower case).

Comment: can you write down your definition of the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s^\ast)$ ?

Comment: Regarding f(t)=g*(t), f(t) is a real function and t is a real variable. So, if f(t)=g*(t) it seems to imply f(t)=g(t) so is there no difference between the inverse Laplace of F(s) and F(s*) ?

Comment: *f(t)=(1/2πi) ∫F(s) e^st ds*  the integral is define between *c-i∞* and *c+i∞* the Laplace *F(s)=∫f(t) e^(-st) dt* the integral from 0 to ∞

Comment: you wrote down the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)$; how do you want to compute the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s^\ast)$ ?

Comment: *g(t)=(1/2πi) ∫F(s**) e^st ds  the integral is define between *c-i∞* and *c+i∞*